# About finding the middle point of a List node in c++

Tags: c++, list

Finding the middle point of a Linked list is a very common method. My question is why the following write-up reports an error (Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)).

```
ListNode* fast = head;
ListNode* slow = head;
while(fast && fast->next){
    fast = fast->next->next;
    slow = slow->next;
}
```

However, I was able to pass with both writes. My question is, what is the reason for this?

```
ListNode* fast = head->next;
ListNode* slow = head;
while(fast && fast->next){
    fast = fast->next->next;
    slow = slow->next;
}
```

And

```
ListNode* fast = head;
ListNode* slow = head;
while(fast->next && fast->next->next){
      fast = fast->next->next;
      slow = slow->next;
}
```

Here is an example of what I wrote.

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};

class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* sortList(ListNode* head) {
        if(!head || !head->next) return head;
        ListNode* fast = head;
        ListNode* slow = head;
        while(fast && fast->next){
            fast = fast->next->next;
            slow = slow->next;
        }
        ListNode* right = slow->next;
        slow->next = nullptr;
        return merge(sortList(head), sortList(right));
    }

    void printList(ListNode* head){
        if(!head) return;
        std::cout << head->val << std::endl;
        printList(head->next);
    }

private:
    ListNode* merge(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2){
        ListNode dummy(0);
        ListNode* tail = &dummy;
        while(l1 && l2){
            if(l1->val > l2->val){
                std::swap(l1, l2);
            }
            tail->next = l1;
            l1 = l1->next;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        if(l1) tail->next = l1;
        if(l2) tail->next = l2;
        return dummy.next;
    }
};


int main() {
    Solution obj;
    std::vector<int> sample = {4,2,1,3};
    ListNode dummy(0);
    ListNode* head = &dummy;
    for(int i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++){
        head->next = new ListNode(sample[i]);
        head = head->next;
    }
    ListNode* ret = obj.sortList(dummy.next);

    obj.printList(ret);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: First of all, you should have debugged to find out the portion of the code that is giving the error. Its the sortList function. Secondly, there is no point in creating the dummy node in your main function.

Comment: Furthermore, the title of this question is so unclear. Middle point of the list? Are you trying to find the middle point or the median?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of iterations `head` is pointing to `4` with `head->next` pointing to `2` and `head->next->next` being null. After your loop `right` is null, `slow` is pointing to `2`, you then set `slow->next` to null (which it already is) and therefore pass an unmodified `head` to the recursive call to `sortList`. This results in infinite recursion and a stack overflow.

Your change simply prevents this situation occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my mistake in writing, slow is not at the midpoint.